# Can I have dist-zilla fill in arbitrary fields in a template file?

Tags: perl, perl-module, dist-zilla

Is there any way to have a *user* defined parameter in a file and then have the `dist.ini` set the value for the parameter. For example, a file might contain `{{$THE_ANSWER}}` and the `dist.ini` file would provide a value like `THE_ANSWER = 42`? I'm pretty new to using `dist::zilla` to work with perl distributions, and I'm having problems understanding how it treats files as templates. There seem to be only a couple of hard-codeed parameters, varying by plugin, that can be used for any file. One such parameter is the {{$NEXT}} variable made available by `[NextRelease]` in the `Changes` file.

I read through the tutorials and searched the modules on CPAN and can't figure out if this is even possible. It is not an acceptable work-around to use the `[GenerateFile]` plugin to put the whole file in the `dist.ini` file. Besides a lack of flexibility and just plain ugliness, it doesn't seem possible to add lines with leading white-space that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is use a stash or plugin to store the variables.  Stashes are like plugins, but they don't *do* anything but store data, and they can be put into your global configuration as well as your `dist.ini`.

```
[%Vars]
favorite_pie = pumpkin
```

Then you can get at them like this:

```
$zilla->stash_named('%Vars')->favorite_pie
```

This assumes that you've made Dist::Zilla::Stash::Vars and given it a favorite_pie attribute.

You could make a totally generic stash, though, which accepts anything as a key.  For that, I'd look at the source of Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Prereqs, which allows arbitrary configuration options and shoves them into a hash attribute in its `BUILDSARGS` method.

You could make that Dist::Zilla::Stash::Generic, and then register it as many times as you want for different reasons:

```
[%Generic / Pies]
favorite  = pumpkin
hated     = rhubarb
firstever = quince

[%Generic / Passwords]
pause  = PeasAreDelicious
google = secret
reddit = SecretPeasAreDelicious
```

...then, as needed, say in templates...

```
{{ $zilla->stash_named('Passwords')->get_var('pause' }}
```

If I was making a lot of files that used this sort of generic thing, I'd pass their Text::Template instance a closure called `get_password` like this:

```
get_password => sub { $zilla->stash_named('Passwords')->get_var($_[0]) }
```

Then your template could include:

```
Login with: {{ get_password("pause") }}
```

This answer obviously leaves some source digging for you, but I think it should point at all the pieces I'd use to do what you want.

Comment: OK, so I can create a specific `Dist::Zilla::Stash::...` module with predefined keys (looks pretty easy), and specify values in `dist.ini` or the global config. If I get tired of editing that and adding new keys, it is possible to create a more general solution. I was kind of hoping that the general case was what `Dist::Zilla::Plugin::GatherDir::Template` could do and that I was just using it wrong; alas.